# How can I downgrade the rxdart plugin in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, rxdart

I followed this as shown (only first 3 minutes are relevant for my question): https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=MYHVyl-juUk

When I try to run it this appears in the console:

Because geoflutterfire 2.0.3+2 depends on rxdart ^0.20.0 and no versions of geoflutterfire match >2.0.3+2 <3.0.0, geoflutterfire ^2.0.3+2 requires rxdart ^0.20.0.
So, because my_app depends on both rxdart ^0.21.0 and geoflutterfire ^2.0.3+2, version solving failed.

The current Version (and the Version I installed) is rxdart 0.21.0. I tried to downgrade it by changing it to 0.20.0 and flutter packages get, but it didn’t work.

Btw, it’s my first time experimenting with plugins, so I don’t have any clue about solving that kind of problems...

What can I do to make this work?

Kind regards

UPDATE:

After I tried this:

```
rxdart: any
```

the console threw this:

```
2019-04-08 12:06:04.178 defaults[36786:354646] 
The domain/default pair of (/Users/privat/Documents/Dev/my_app/ios/Runner/Info, CFBundleIdentifier) does not exist


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geoflutterfire-2.0.3+2/ios/Classes/GeoflutterfirePlugin.m:2:9: fatal error:
    'geoflutterfire/geoflutterfire-Swift.h' file not found
    #import <geoflutterfire/geoflutterfire-Swift.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
```

Then I edited the Podfile Code:
Code that needed to be added or edited are marked with "** ...... **"

```
    target 'Runner' do
      ** use_frameworks!  **
    ........ ......

    post_install do |installer|
          installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
              config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
              ** config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0' **
            end
          end
        end
```

Then I deleted my Podfile.lock and tried again, and the app was compiled successfully. **Thanks to C4C!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this edits in Podfile
Code needs to be added or edited are marked with "** ...... **"

```
target 'Runner' do
  ** use_frameworks!  **
........ ......

post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
          ** config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0' **
        end
      end
    end
```

delete your Podfile.lock and try

Comment: I'm in! Thank you so much! :))

Answer (score 1):

```
rxdart:any
```

Give it a try and let us know what happens

Comment: I referenced the console output in the main post as an update. Thanks mate!

Comment: I have posted new answer please try and let us know

Answer (score 0):

Older versions can be found here - https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/rxdart#-versions-tab-

If you are receiving AndroidX errors due to the older version then please check this page to resolve AndroidX issues - https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility

Comment: thank you! how can I install an older version? 

I tried to compile it to an android device but it isn't working.